# Keras Conv1D as first layer

Tags: python, keras

Keras documentation includes this bit on the section of Conv1D

> When using this layer as the first layer in a model, provide an input_shape argument (tuple of integers or None, e.g. (10, 128) for sequences of 10 vectors of 128-dimensional vectors, or (None, 128) for variable-length sequences of 128-dimensional vectors.

I am wondering why this is required and why it is not required to provide the inputs shape elsewhere in the model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's about how layers are connected. The layers after the first layer are *chained* so their input shapes are equal to the output shape of the previous layer in a sequential model:

```
model.layers[i].input_shape == model.layers[i-1].output_shape
```

But what about the very first layer? Since the model *cannot* infer what the shape should be, it asks you to provide it. After the first input all the shapes can be calculated.