# What to expect from model.predict in Keras?

Tags: keras

I am new to Keras and trying to write my first code. I want to understand what 'model.predict' should return. Consider a simple model below.

```
model = keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(12, input_dim=232, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(232, activation='relu'))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
# compile the keras model
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
# fit the keras model on the dataset
model.fit(vSignal, vLabels, epochs=15, batch_size=100 )
# evaluate the keras model
_, accuracy = model.evaluate(vSignal, vLabels)
print('Accuracy: %.2f' % (accuracy*100))

pred=model.predict(vSignalT)
```

Consider we train the "model" with "vSignal" and "vLabels" as shown above. Now consider that the accuracy of the model as given by model.evaluate is 100%. Now if we give same data 'vSignal' to 'model.predict' should we get the 'vLabels' return?

Comment: No, you would not get vLabels, only after some post-processing to transform probabilities into clas labels.

Answer (score 1):

`pred=model.predict(vSignalT)` returns a numpy arrays of predictions.
each row consists of one of the `vlabels` that the model predicted.
**for more information refer to [here](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/)**

save return value of fit function:

```
hist = model.fit(vSignal, vLabels, epochs=15, batch_size=100 );
```

then check the

```
hist.history["accuracy"]
```

Comment: The surprise is : I get 100% accuracy but not the vLabels so what is going on? My vLabels are only 0 and 1 that means I have only 2 class. Can you please help?

Comment: I have just updated the answer. hope it help you

Comment: Softmax is used for multi-classification problems for binary like the one in the question sigmoid is used. Further, the unit should be 1 not 2 for the last layer.

Comment: You helped me with this question, can you help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51953766/keras-conv1d-as-first-layer, please?